# Where did my "Run Django Console" menu go?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

There is long time I don't use a Django console, but I used to see a menu in IntelliJ IDEA software under Tools (i.e. Tools > Run Django Console).

When I saw the menu, it had the green-white Django icon with title "Run Django Console", right above the "Run Python Console" icon. This is my menu using IntelliJ 14 (See the last item. It is "Run Python Console". "Run Django Console" should be immediately above):

[image: See the last item. It is Run Python Console. Run Django Console should be immediately above]

Is there something I can do to restore that menu? Or is it gone forever in IntelliJ 14's PyCharm plugin?

Answer (score 4):

[The doc page about `Running Console`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/running-console.html) has a tip:

> When the current project is a Django project, the console that starts is *Django Console*. However, if the current project is pure Python project, then PyCharm starts *Python Console*.

In the settings `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Django Console` there is a starting script that is supposed to work, yet in intellij 2017.3.5 it seems to be deprecated.

I have written a simple replacement of the original starting script, with which it is possible to overwrite `Python Console`'s starting script and it will behave just as `Django Console` did. Only that script will also require to manually define `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in `Python Console`'s environmental variables.

```
import os
from runpy import run_module

import django
from django.core import management


def execute_django_manage_file():
    def execute_from_command_line_stub(argv=None):
        pass
    management.execute_from_command_line = execute_from_command_line_stub

    django_manage_file = os.getenv('PYCHARM_DJANGO_MANAGE_MODULE')
    if not django_manage_file:
        django_manage_file = 'manage'

    run_module(
        mod_name=django_manage_file,
        init_globals=None,
        run_name='__main__',
        alter_sys=True,
    )


django.setup()
execute_django_manage_file()
```